# Under "System Settings -> Details" "Graphics" shown as "Unknown"

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, xorg, package-management

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop. System details shown by Ubuntu are as:

- Memory: 3.8 GB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4
- Graphics: Unknown
- OS: type 32-bit

---

Now I don't understand why graphics is 'unknown'. Isn't it supposed to show

> **Graphics: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)**

(as I don't have any other graphic card installed on my motherboard, so it should show the default one).

When I executed:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

it showed

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Then I executed:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

And it gave following as output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

So over all I'm stuck here and don't know what to do.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

for the graphics unknown problem run

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

for broken packages run:

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks guyz for ur quick reply..............n yeah it did worked!!!